# What is known about the transformation of a power series in which $z^n$ is replaced with $z^{n^2}$?

Tags: transformation, power-series

Say we have the function $$G(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} g_n z^n.$$

Is there a name for the transform T defined so that $$(T(G))(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} g_n z^{n^2}?$$

Is there anything known about this kind of transformation?

Comment: Well, they become lacunary most of the time, and z usually becomes restricted to be within the unit disk after such a change.

Comment: The original series does not really bear a strong relation to the new series.  I don't think this is a useful definition.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think it actually becomes lacunary in this case. I think that it pretty much has the same properties as the original series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function

Comment: @Eric: it really doesn't.  For example, the "transform" of the innocent rational function 1/(1-z) is a much more complicated beast: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: There might be good applications in Hilbert space theory or on $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}_+)$, where the map is linear and norm preserving (considering $z^n$ as a 'base').

Comment: @AD.: it doesn't preserve any multiplicative structure.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Well, on $\ell^1$ it is multiplicative. Hence,  we do at least have that $r(f)=r(G(f))$ where $r(f)$ is the spectral radius of $f$.

Comment: @AD.: right, but that's true of any transformation where one replaces z^n with z^{f(n)} for some f.  The vast majority of these transformations do not admit interesting analytic descriptions and are - I will say it again - not useful.  It will take a significant application to convince me otherwise.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Sure, you may be right. However, to me it is not obvious that there is no application. :)

Comment: What I had in mind were combinatorial applications -- in particular replacing $z^n$ with $z^\binom{n}{p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a formula for the ordinary generating function of the sequence and its $j^{th}$ derivatives, which must exist for all $j \geq 0$, then [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02803) (2017) provides you with an integral representation of the transformed series in question. In particular, if $G(z)$ is the ordinary generating function of the sequence $\{g_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $0 < |q| < 1$, then we have proved in the article that 
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} g_n q^{n^2} z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} 
     \left[\sum_{b = \pm 1} G\left(e^{bt \sqrt{2\log(q)} z}\right)\right] e^{-t^2 / 2} dt. $$ The article terms this general procedure for modifying the original sequence generating function a *square series transformation integral*, but more generally, some of the most interesting applications of this method include new integral representations for theta functions and classical identities such as the series expansion for *Jacobi's triple product*.

Comment: links seems to be broken now

Comment: Fixed the link to the arxiv version. Thanks.

Comment: Inside $G$ it should be $e^{bt \sqrt{2\log(q)}}z$, right?

Comment: Yes, fixing it now.